# Can't do LSD.test in loop For in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to do LSD test in loop for multi parameter. Here my code

```
library(agricolae)

bbb<-aov(ent[,5]~ent[,2],data = ent)
LSD.test(bbb,"sal.",group = TRUE,console = TRUE)
```

Here is data:
sal.   pH    EC
sal.3   6.0  690
sal.3   5.8  730
sal.3   5.7  620
sal.6   6.3  550
sal.6   6.3  770
sal.6   6.3  250

And this is the result:

```
Name:  sal. 
 ent[, 2]
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(ent)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(ent, 20))`.

Comment: And where are the `for` loops?